# Reducing window size moves elements

Tags: html, css, resize

Hello awesome programmers,

I have been struggling greatly with CSS for some time now. I have an issue when resizing a window, some of my divs begin to collapse down the page. (As shown)

Before:

[before http://411metrics.com/pics/before.PNG](http://411metrics.com/pics/before.PNG)

After:

[before http://411metrics.com/pics/after.PNG](http://411metrics.com/pics/after.PNG)

I have tried setting the min-width to 100% on various divs and also tried setting the overflow to hidden.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

My HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="branding-logo"><img src="/Portal/images/sharktek-logo.png" width="35" height="35"></div>
    <div id="branding">Sharktek Tracking</div>
    <div id="link-wrap">
        <div id="active-nav"><a href="/Portal/dashboard">Dashboard</a></div>
        <a href="/Portal/statistic">Reports</a>
        <a href="/Portal/record">Call Logs</a>
        <a href="/Portal/manage">Manage Campaigns</a>';         
    </div>
    <div id="nav-user">
        Welcome<br>
        <a href="/Portal/account">Account Settings</a>
        <a href="/Portal/auth/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="nav-accent"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#navigation {
    z-index:3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(22, 29, 37,1);
    color: rgba(1, 172, 237, 1);
}


#navigation a {
    float:left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#link-wrap {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

#active-nav{
    z-index: 2;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    height: 60px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#346c83, rgba(1, 172, 237, 1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#346c83, rgba(1, 172, 237, 1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#346c83, rgba(1, 172, 237, 1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#346c83, rgba(1, 172, 237, 1)); /* Standard syntax */
}

#active-nav a:hover {
    color:white;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: grey;
} 

#branding-logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#branding{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size:1.4em;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}


#nav-accent {
    z-index:2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(1, 172, 237, 0.95);
    color: rgba(1, 172, 237, 1);
}
#nav-user {
    color: white;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 30px 0 0;
    font-size: .8em;
    float:right;
}

#nav-user a{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size:.8em;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to give up something here. If you want responsiveness, then you need to code for responsive behaviors, defining what will happen at certain sizes. It's obvious that no matter what, at some point elements won't fit. In this situation... what do you want to happen? Based on that, you may have different answers. Right now, you can have that element with position:absolute and it will work.... until you see that element overlapping everything else on resize

Comment: Well, I didn't go through your Code just at a glance your problem I would suggest you to switch to bootstrap grid system for designing your layouts. And I am sure once you get used to it, you'll never look back.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems until I started to understand and apply absolute positioning. i.e. positioning relative the div you are in.

For absolute positioning the parent div must be set to relative positioning and after that you fix your inner elements to whatever side you like without having the browser take over the flow control.

e.g. in your case, with ...

```
#link-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    /* ... the rest */
}
```

... your nav links will stop jumping all over the page. I made a few more tweaks in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xb9cdu34/2/ .

Comment: This is a HORRIBLE suggestion, both for the specific case as well as in general. Absolute positioning shouldn't be loved or hated, it has to be used when it's needed and avoided at all costs when not needed. And of course, this is a paramount example of when absolute position is NOT needed unless you add quite a lot more of code, including media queries

Comment: What I mean is that solution will work ONLY if you add a lot more code than this, including ALL elements behaviors with ALL media queries for ALL sizes. So yes, it's a lot more code. Just do an experiment: open your fiddle and resize it. I'm not saying a lot, just resize it to around 900px width and see what happens with your position:absolute element, then you'll understand what I mean (just in case you didn't notice, your element will be overlapping everything else)

Comment: @Fabio, ok, I understand where you are coming from now. In my view the first step is to make the page work in a web browser. Right now things go badly wrong once the page is resized. With the absolute positioning solution I provide it looks (to me) like a normal web page. My solution is not robust enough for all cases but I still think it will work for the majority. I would still be curious to find out what an optimal solution might look like. Thanks for the feedback!